# Granting device-location-access

Tags: bixby

What is the recommended way to ask for a person's location?  The documentation seems to be [incomplete](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule.permissions).

Previously, you would use **user-profile-access** but that has been deprecated.  Yet, the documentation for **device-location-access** states '*This is a beta feature and doesn't yet have documentation*'

When using device-location-access...the simulator (and device) still ask for the contacts as if I'm using the deprecated 'user-profile-access' permission.  Here are the current settings.

**capsule.bxb**

```
permissions {
    device-location-access
  }
```

**capsule-info.bxb**

```
requested-permissions {
    permission (device-location-access) {
      justification (Access your location to provide local deals)
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, `user-profile-access` is the only way to get this information.

`device-location-access` is expected to be available soon (probably as early as next week) at which point that will be the recommended way to get the user's location.

Comment: Great, and thanks for sharing the anticipated availability.